# Filling in with pgfplots and draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I created the following polygon:

```
\tikz
\draw[very thick,name path=A] (0,15) to [out=0,in=270] (15,30);
\draw[very thick, name path=B] (0,15) to [out=0,in=90] (15,0);
\draw[very thick,name path=C] (15,0) to [out=90,in=180] (30,15);
\draw[very thick,name path=D] (30,15) to [out=180,in=270] (15,30);
```

and would like to fill it without modifying how I wrote the polygon. Is there an easy way to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill, then draw:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\fill[green] 
  (0,15) to [out=0,in=90] 
  (15,0) to [out=90,in=180] 
  (30,15) to [out=180,in=270] 
  (15,30) to [out=270,in=0] 
  (0,15);
\draw[very thick,name path=A] (0,15) to [out=0,in=270] (15,30);
\draw[very thick, name path=B] (0,15) to [out=0,in=90] (15,0);
\draw[very thick,name path=C] (15,0) to [out=90,in=180] (30,15);
\draw[very thick,name path=D] (30,15) to [out=180,in=270] (15,30);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the name for the paths are not relevant, you could simplify to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\filldraw[very thick,fill=green] 
  (0,15) to [out=0,in=90] (15,0)
  to [out=90,in=180] (30,15)
  to [out=180,in=270] (15,30) 
  to [out=270,in=0] (0,15);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but you required not to change the original code, thus my first solution.

Comment: A not related question: I have an arrow like this     \node[single arrow,draw=black,fill=black!10,minimum height=6cm,minimum width=6cm,,shape border rotate=335] at (3,27);
 but I can't rotate it besides the classical 90, 180, 270 degrees. Can you help me with that please? Thanks so much!

Comment: Solved! It is "rotate" alone.